# Least square method in python

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy, least-squares

I have two lists of data, one with x values and the other with corresponding y values. How can I find the best fit? I've tried messing with `scipy.optimize.leastsq` but I just can't seem to get it right.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If you're just doing a [linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)) fit it might be simpler just to do the math yourself rather than looking for a library. Something like `scipy.optimize.leastsq` is a lot more complicated than you need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it would be simpler to use `numpy.polyfit`, which performs Least squares polynomial fit. This is a simple snippet:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
y = np.array([2.1, 2.9, 4.15, 4.98, 5.5, 6])

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)

#plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xp = np.linspace(-1, 6, 100)
plt.plot(x, y, '.', xp, p(xp))
plt.show()
```

[image]